# while loop with next value

Tags: java, while-loop

I want to take the key and values in the while loop

```
while (rs.next()) {
     String simpleData = "<SimpleData name="akey">avalue</SimpleData>\n";
}
```

I need to take all the key and values. If I have 10 values available in resultset, then the simple data should contain all the key and values. like below

**Output**:- finally my string should be like below
    String

```
 simpleData = "<SimpleData name="acolumnname">acolumnvalue</SimpleData>
               <SimpleData name="bcolumnname">bcolumnvalue</SimpleData>
             …";
```

How can I achieve

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder` and `append(simpleData)` in every iteration... Maybe remove the last `"\n"` if necessary.

Comment: @deHaar thanks for the reply how can I print the key and value

Comment: `rs.getString(0)` and `rs.getString(1)`, maybe... You haven't provided a sample output of the `ResultSet`.

Comment: @deHaar I want to find until the last key and value in the resultset, I don't know how many key and values are going to be there

Comment: if it is for loop we can use the i value, so that we will get the each data

Comment: That's why you are using `while (rs.next())`, it gets you alle the resulting rows...

Comment: Can you show a desired result (example)?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case but if you want `"` in your String, you need to type `\"`. Also, what is `rs`?

Comment: @Ecto rs contains the database values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an xml structure *by hand* (that means without making use of a suitable library), you can try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ResultSet rs = // however you get it

    // get the meta data of the result set, they are including the column headers
    ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
    // and get the first column header
    String columnHeader = resultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel(1);

    // initialize an empty StringBuilder OUTSIDE the loop
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // then loop through the resultset
    while (rs.next()) {
        // appending the results to the StringBuilder
        sb.append("<SimpleData name=\"")    // opening tag plus xml attribute name
        .append(columnHeader)               // column header as determined before the loop
        .append("\">")                      // close the opening tag and the attribute value
        .append(rs.getString(1))            // get the value from the result set
        .append("</SimpleData>")            // write the closing tag
        .append(System.lineSeparator());    // append a line break
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

This should be printing an xml structure (hopefully the desired one):

```xml
<SimpleData name="column header">value</SimpleData>
```

**EDIT**
Turned out you want to create a single xml node for each column value of a result set that has only one row. That's (nearly totally) different...
I would then access the columns by their alias (header / label) instead of their index:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    ResultSet rs = null; // however you get it
    // create a container for the headers
    List<String> columnHeaders = new ArrayList<>();
    // get the meta data of the result set, they are including the column headers
    ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
    // determine the amount of columns
    int columnCount = resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount();

    // iterate them and store their values in a list of strings
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        columnHeaders.add(resultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel(i));
    }

    // initialize an empty StringBuilder OUTSIDE the loop
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // then loop through the resultset
    while (rs.next()) {
        // now loop through the columnHeaders
        for (String header : columnHeaders) {
            // append each column result to the StringBuilder as a single xml node
            sb.append("<SimpleData name=\"")    // opening tag plus xml attribute name
            .append(header)                     // column header as determined before the loop
            .append("\">")                      // close the opening tag and the attribute value
            .append(rs.getString(header))       // get the value from the result set by header, not index
            .append("</SimpleData>")            // write the closing tag
            .append(System.lineSeparator());    // append a line break              
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare simpleData outside the while loop and in every iteration you should append to simpleData by +=

```
String simpleData ;
int i ; 
while (rs.next()) {
  simpleData   += "<SimpleData name="+key+" "+rs.getString(i)+"</SimpleData>\n";
i++;
}
```

Comment: please provide sample output

Comment: ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData() ;
rs.getColumnName(colunm_number) ;

Comment: declare a variable i outside while loop and place i inside it ==>  rs.getString(i) and increment i  in ever iteration

Comment: Then there is just one row returned

Comment: Previsouly in while loop we again declaring simpleData like "String simpleData" .This will created a new string every time (Every Iteration ) .

Comment: Try to print the no of rows in the resultSet . Try this :
rs.last();
System.out.prinltn("No of rows = " + rs.getRow());

Comment: I think  you need to exceute commit statement  in database